# Ruby not working on windows term 'rails' is not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, windows-10

I’m using Windows 10, installed Ruby 2.6.14 and bash 4.3.42(5). And I can’t run ruby, the error follows below:

```
PS F:\App\App> rails c
rails : The term 'rails' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ rails c
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (rails:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

In edit environment variable, I have : C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you need to install rails with

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not installed rails, The error is saying the command rails is not found in path. Follow below steps to fix this issue

1. Install rails using gem (gem install rails), usually it should fix problems
2. If above steps doesn't work then check your path in environment, If it is not pointing to rails command then updating path should fix this issue

Comment: In edit environment variable, I have : C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\

Comment: In path C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ check whether you have file called rails.bat. If you have file with rails.bat then it should work else some issue with the rails installation we'll see